# How can i open access to Opportunity Activities?

Tags: opportunity, activities, sharing-rule, digital-experience, owd

- User 1 is the owner of an opportunity and he has activities.
- User 2 is same in the hierarchy comparing to the first user but

  - he cannot see the first user's opportunity activities on digital experience,
  - he can see the opportunity record though.
- The OWD for opportunity is private and for activity is controlled by the parent.

Would appreciate some advices. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  You should use [edit] and demonstrate some research in order to get the Community to assist